read all mp4 files in the folder
I want to read all mp4 files in the folder but when running it doesn't work, I want to read file 1.mp4 when it finishes running it automatically runs 2.mp4 .... n.mp4.
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('f:\\a'):
    for file in files:
        tt = (os.path.join(root,file))
        print(tt)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(tt)

    while (cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == True:


            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                break

        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


I have put in a loop (for) but it only shows a list of files (cv2.imshow('frame', frame), please guide me.

Why your code after cap = cv2.VideoCapture(tt) is not in the for file in files block? These code are not iterating through all files under the folder.

do you understand what your for-loop does?

I see you only run the last file in this directory, which VideoCapture outside for loop files, so please re-check this.
Before reading the list of files, you should filter out the files you want to open. In this case, it is the mp4 file with the extension .mp4. Below is your code after being slightly modified. Hope it can help you!
import os
import cv2

files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('.mp4')]

for file in files:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)

    if not cap.isOpened():
        print(f"Error opening video file {file}")
        continue

    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break

    cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()


Can you show me the details because I've been trying for a long time but it still doesn't work. It only lists the mp4 files (Print), not (cv2.imshow) each mp4 file.

I know (if ret:false), so I can't cv2.imshow

@Kanguyenvan When running cv2.imshow, it will open each mp4 file in turn. Have you checked if your current directory contains any mp4 files again?

In my folder there are 15 mp4 files, I don't know where (cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file) is wrong so ret = false, please guide me

Note that you have to call the function cv2.VideoCapture(file), which will be used to capture all frames of the mp4 video. If your mp4 file does not contain any frames (only music), then this will not run.
Additionally, the frames will run very fast because you set cv2.waitKey(1), which means the time delay is 1ms = 0.001s, resulting in FPS = 1000 and causing the window to close immediately when it starts.

Thank you for your instructions. I set the path like this (cap = cv2.VideoCapture("f:\a\b.mp4") then (cv2.imshow) and (cv2.waitKey(200) ) work fine. I'm stuck with the for function. I don't know where I went wrong. Please guide me.

Code outside for loop
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('f:\\a'):
    for file in files: // You iterate through all files here
        tt = (os.path.join(root,file))
        print(tt)
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(tt) // Why this code is not inside the loop 

    // ...

You should put all code depending on the current file you are iterating inside the for file in files loop.
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('f:\\a'):
    for file in files: // You iterate through all files here
        tt = (os.path.join(root,file))
        print(tt)
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(tt)

        // Remember to put the remaining code also into the for block
        // ...

Code style problems
while (cap.isOpened()):

Python does not require parentheses in if, for, while and other statements, so the () around cap.isOpened() is redundant:
while cap.isOpened():

Another problem is:
if ret == True:

ret is already a bool, so you can simply write
if ret:

cv2.waitKey()
You called cv2.waitKey() method. Please be aware that the parameter you pass is the maximum timeout this method will wait for, in millisecond. If you expect to wait for 1s, you should use cv2.waitKey(1000).
Advice
Personally, I think you are not familiar with basic Python grammar. I recommend you to review it to avoid mistakes in future programming.

Thanks for your comment!

I thank you all very much for your comments and corrections. Thanks to your corrections and comments, my program now runs well. I wish you good health.
